# Javascript command to click when color is detected

Tags: javascript, html

I'm pretty new to all this so my apologies if I say something that doesn't make sense.
I'm looking for a way to detect the color under a cursor, and if it matches a certain, predetermined color, the mouse will click. Javascript optimally, something I can just input into the console. I'm guessing it's just some if-then statement but I can't figure out how to detect the color (it can either be under the cursor or at a certain point on the screen, it doesn't really matter).

Thanks

Comment: do you want to get color from IMAGE/canvaas - or it can by any element like button/div/text... etc. ?

Comment: @Kamil any element I think. I'm trying to game those reaction time tests like [this](https://www.humanbenchmark.com/tests/reactiontime).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In link you provide in comment ([this](https://www.humanbenchmark.com/tests/reactiontime)) you can detect color  changes by this code (when you run it in browser - when green color appear then in console you will see 'green' word 3x)

```
var observer = new MutationObserver((mutations, observer) => { mutations.map( m => {
  let d = document.querySelector('div.test-standard.reaction-time-test.view-go > div > div:nth-child(1) > h1 > div');
  if(d) { console.log('green'); }
})});

observer.observe(document.querySelector('#root'), {attributes: true,childList: true, subtree: true });
```

but click-ing you must do by yourself